# Spotify app, create custom modules

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm trying to develop a small Spotify App but have some issues. I have an object `Foo` that I want to keep in a separate file and require in my main file. Then in my main file I want to create objects like this: `var baz = new Foo(some, arguments)`. But I can't get it to work.

I'm using the 1.0 version of the API and Spotify uses requirejs in some form, right?

Example: https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/blob/1.0/js/tutorial.js

So, I tried to do it like this using two files, foo.js and main.js.

```
// main.js
require([
  '$api/models',
  'foo'], function(models, Foo) {

  var f = new Foo("hello", "world");

  ...
});

// foo.js
// define() doesn't work? So I tried with require again...?!
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {

  function Foo(some, arg) {
    this.some = some;
    this.arg  = arg;
  }

  Foo.prototype.getSome() { return this.some; }


  return Foo;

});
```

This gives me an error "Object is not a function" in the main file when doing `new Foo(..)`.

Why is that? I guess it is because I use require() in foo.js? What should I use instead then?

Edit:
Ok, so it seems I should use `exports`, such as: `exports.myMethod = myMethod;`

But then I need to export a method that creates and returns an instance of a Foo object with all of its instance methods etc, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

```
//foo.js
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {

  var Foo = (function() {
    var foo = function(some, arg) {
        // Do stuff..
    };
    return foo;
  })();

  exports.Foo = Foo;
});
```

Then in main.js I require it like this:
require(['scripts/foo#Foo']...

Seems to work OK. Don't  know if it is the best approach though.

Comment: It is ok, though in your example, the value of Foo is the foo function. It is enough with writing your functions as usual, and assign to `exports` the ones you want to expose.